# How many groups of order $2016$ exists, which are a direct product of smaller groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, products, gap

There are $6538$ groups of order $2016$ upto isomorphism.

> How many groups of order $2016$ are a direct product of (at least two) smaller groups ?

I calculated an upper bound by summing the products of $gnu(j)\times gnu(\frac{2016}{j})$ over the divisors $j$ of $2016$ with $1<j\le \sqrt{2016}$, but his sum is even larger than $6538$.

I constructed the direct products, but it is virtually unfeasible to count how many groups are pairwise non-isomorphic with. for example, SONATA.

So, which restriction to the groups do I need to find out the required number ?

Comment: Computed the list - took 11 minutes. ` ForAll(g,IsGroup);` returns true. So this is the case here, these 6538 groups should be non-isomorphic.

Comment: GAP has an undocumented `DirectFactorsOfGroup` attribute used by `StructureDescription`. With its help, I've calculated that there are 3079 groups for which `DirectFactorsOfGroup` can not find factorisation into the direct product, hence 3459 of these groups are direct products. I don't exactly know which assumptions are used in `DirectFactorsOfGroup`, so I think it is safe to say that there are **AT LEAST** 3459 groups of order 2016 which are direct products of smaller groups.

Comment: Also, I still don't see why SONATA is useful here, and why checking isomorphism is unfeasible. You need to start to break the set into clusters and then refine them using more and more invariants.

Comment: Yes, it takes a while. I had to restart it with a for loop to print the progress of calculation, and increase the memory limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAP has an undocumented attribute `DirectFactorsOfGroup` which is used by `StructureDescription`. With its help, I've calculated that there are 3079 groups for which `DirectFactorsOfGroup` can not find factorisation into the direct product, hence the remaining 3459 groups of order 2016 are direct products.

Just in case of `DirectFactorsOfGroup` works under some assumptions and may miss some factorisations (after all, it's not documented!), I think it is safe to say that there are **AT LEAST** 3459 groups of order 2016 which are direct products of smaller groups.

I guess that your calculation of the upper bound returned $7466$ groups:

```
gap> n:=Filtered([2..46],i -> IsInt(2016/i));
[ 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 28, 32, 36, 42 ]
gap> Sum(List(n,j->NrSmallGroups(j)*NrSmallGroups(2016/j)));
7466
```

which is more than twice more. This is not surprising, since some groups may be represented as direct products in more than one way.

It should be still feasible to generate these 7466 direct products and then classify them up to isomorphism. You need to start to break their set into clusters using some easily computed invariants (e.g. the order of the centre, the number of conjugacy classes etc.) and then refine them using more and more invariants, and apply hard tests only to the refined clusters.

Comment: Please check if my intermediate result after $1000$ groups : [ 579, 290, 63, 45, 15, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0 ]
is correct!

Comment: What do these numbers mean?

Comment: The groups with $1$, $2$ , $3$,... direct factors.

Comment: Unfortunately, my program crashed. I got the error message : "cannot extend the workspace anymore" and could not return to GAP. How can I increase the memory to avoid this ?

Comment: Yes, same numbers for the 1st thousand. To increase memory limit, start GAP with `-o 4G` option for example. On Windows, the actual physical limit may happen to be lower though. If so, try to calculate it for one group at a time, not storing groups that are done already.

Comment: How can I delete the calculated values ? GAP automatically stores what it calculates ...

Comment: Try `Unbind(list[i])` - this will remove the $i$-th entry of the list - fine If you don't have to store groups for further calculation. Otherwise, for $i$-th group you need to create a new isomorphic copy, calculate its number of direct factors and then throw it away.

Comment: I could calculate the vector by "throwing away" every group I have analyzed. $$[ 3079, 2170, 906, 283, 74, 20, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]$$ was the result. Please check! It is annoying that the groups get lost this way. There is no way to recover the elements, right ? Do you have an alternative idea ?

Comment: Alternative is to create a new isomorphic copy for i-th group, calculate its number of direct factors and then throw this copy away. This will not change the original list.

Comment: I did not try this because I feared that the program crashes again because the original list occupies the memory. Annyoing is that the error "cannot extend the workspace anymore" is irreversible that means I cannot return to GAP, but the program hangs up and I have to close it. There is a prompt "press enter to return", but it does not work. A windows-issue ?

Comment: I'm sure this is Windows :(

Comment: Believe it or not, even x:=AllSmallGroups(256); is too much for my windows version, awful :(

Comment: @Peter, but why one would ever need to call `AllSmallGroups(256)` ? Just enumerate them one by one as follows:  `for n in [1..NrSmallGroups(256)] do G:=SmallGroup(256,n) "do some useful stuff" od;` For order 2016, we had to keep them only because this order is not available via `SmallGroup` (and of course if we would be desperate, we could save them info a file and load later).

Comment: I simply wanted to check that the $56092$ groups are non-isomorphic. I know, that many sources claim this, but sometimes a wrong result is repeated by many sources, so I simply wanted to calculate the groups to be sure. Not important, but annyoing that this seems to be impossible under windows.

Comment: What I do not understand : How can $56092$ groups of order $256$ occupy so many bytes, that GAP crashes ?

Comment: To be precise, `MemoryUsage(AllSmallGroups(256))` reports 223174848 bytes, that is 223 Mb (this is in 64-bit version of GAP). Is `AllSmallGroups(256)` failing on your machine even in a clean new GAP session?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is. Maybe, you can make the check and, if you have nothing better to do, you can check the above vector as well : $[3079,2170,...]$

Comment: I tried to execute GAP with the option -m 500m. Why does this not work ? And how can I see how many bytes are used and how many are free ?

Comment: OK, I will try to find some time to discuss this with you in chat and try to understand what's going on on your machine. `-m` is initial memory that GAP requests. Try e.g. `-o 2G` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38072/discussion-between-peter-and-alexander-konovalov).