# In GAP, How can I check whether a given group is a direct product?

Tags: group-theory, gap, direct-product

I'm working with GAP and I want to make some check through all small group up to given size. For direct product groups the result is depend on the groups it composed of, so I don't want to waste time on such groups. Is there a built-in option to check whether a group is a (not trivial) direct product?

Comment: Of course, I can get this information from the group description but it's not so elegant...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the command `StructureDescription(G)` which gives a name for the group $G$ and could tell you whether $G$ is a direct product or not. However, it just gives you a string and not the subgroups giving the decomposition.

But in the algorithm of `StructureDescription` (described [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X87BF1B887C91CA2E)) a decomposition is found at some point. According to the answer given by Alexander Konovalov [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1726453/17384), the command `StructureDescription` uses the undocumented method `DirectFactorsOfGroup` to do this.

So you can use

```
DirectFactorsOfGroup(G);
```

which returns a list $[G_1, \ldots, G_n]$ such that $G = G_1 \times \cdots \times G_n$. I suppose this will always return $G_i$ which are directly indecomposable, since the algorithm of `StructureDescription` states that we "Decompose G into a direct product of irreducible factors.".

Comment: I experimented with an elementary abelian group of order $2^{10}$. StructureDescription returned the decomposition immediately, but DirectFactorsOfGroup is taking forever (and it is also using a lot of memory). Perhaps it is trying to find all normal subgroups which, as I said in my answer, is not always a good idea!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Thanks, I did not realize this. According to the documentation, StructureDescription will first check if the group is abelian and decompose it in a different way (elementary divisors). So I suppose here too one should first check if the group is abelian, and if not, use DirectFactorsOfGroup. Which, as you say, might still be very slow. I wonder now what kind of algorithm this command uses, and what kind of algorithms are out there for decomposing groups into direct products.

Comment: For me that's a great solution cause I'm working with small groups. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 6):

The question would be more interesting if you asked how you might do this rather than asking whether there is a command to do it in GAP.

Here is a first suggestion, which you could easily implements in GAP. There might be better ways.

Start by finding all nontrivial proper normal subgroups of $G$. For each such subgroup $N$ compute its centralizer $C_G(N)$ in $G$. If $NC_G(N) = G$, then check among your list of normal subgroups to see if any of them lie in $C_G(N)$ and complement $N$.

The first step would be a bit silly if for example $G$ was a large elementary abelian group, so you might want to start by checking if the group is abelian, in which case it is a direct product iff it is not cyclic of prime power order.

I am sure there other situations in which finding all normal subgroups would be a bad idea because there are too many of them, such as extraspecial $p$-groups, which are not direct products, so I am only suggesting this as a first attempt.